# Pandas read_csv with quotes in filename

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've seen lots of answers on how to deal with quotes within the data, but can't find anything to do with a single quote in the filename

I received a file titled Actual CF's. How do I get read_csv to ignore the single quote in the filename

Comment: You can read it like this `pd.read_csv('Actual CF\'s.csv')` or `pd.read_csv("Actual CF's.csv")`

Comment: Wil the same process work if I'm reading from a path like c:\user\me\cf's\john's.csv

Comment: '\' is the escape character so that the character right after it will be treated as a normal string. That's why `'Actual CF\'s.csv'` works. If you want to use `'\'` as a string, do `'\\'` instead. Please test it out.

Comment: When I put the \ in the right place it worked, doh!. Thanks for your help